# a better use of re to avoid making a double pass

Tags: python, regex, functional-programming, repeat

any ideas on how to improve this approach?

The idea is to keep joining-hyphens, but to remove them when they stand alone. 
sample output is shown

```
def de_punctuate(xs):
    reg = re.findall(r"[\w'-]+", xs)
    #the pupose of `fun` is to only remove any hyphens that stand alone.
    #i want to keep hyphens-as-joining
    fun = functools.partial(operator.ne, '-')
    return filter(fun, reg)

def no_numbers(xs):
    isa = functools.partial(operator.contains, string.digits)
    fn = lambda x: ''.join(itertools.filterfalse(isa, x))
    return list(filter(fn, xs))

for d in data:
    print(d)
    print(no_numbers(de_punctuate(d)))
```

output examples:

```
Turistguide fikk 40.000 kroner i bot for smugling
['Turistguide', 'fikk', 'kroner', 'i', 'bot', 'for', 'smugling']

- Må kalles opp etter Dale Oen
['Må', 'kalles', 'opp', 'etter', 'Dale', 'Oen']

Kvinne skadet i MC-ulykke ved Haugastøl
['Kvinne', 'skadet', 'i', 'MC-ulykke', 'ved', 'Haugastøl']
```

the output is how I want it. But I have the feeling than an improved regex would help!

this looks a bit cleaner I think:

```
def de_punctuate(xs):
    return re.findall(r"[\w']+(?:-[\w']+)*", xs)

def no_numbers(xs):
    return [ x for x in xs if not re.search(r'[0-9]', x) ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
re.findall(r"[\w']+(?:-[\w']+)*", myString)
```

For

```
myString = "walk-the-dog can - i - --have -- a- -- look at your pocket-book?"
```

This yields:

```
['walk-the-dog', 'can', 'i', 'have', 'a', 'look', 'at', 'your', 'pocket-book']
```

Comment: (+1) Any reason why you've used `r"\w+(?:-\w+)?"` instead of `r"\w+(?:-\w+)*"`?

Comment: @mgilson : Because I neglected to think of the case: "run-of-the-mill". Good catch. Editing.

Comment: I wonder what should happen in the case: "run--of--the--mill".  I don't think that's particularly clear.

Comment: +1 despite not having Norwegian example strings. As for the "run--off" problem, there are no good sol—utions (especially once Unicode gets in the mix).

Comment: just one question. where do i add the `'` so I can keep abbreviated words?

Comment: @mgilson: Well, double hyphenation (`--`) is traditionally used to denote a dash, which has a completely different meaning from a hyphen. In that case, "run--of--the--mill" is a collection of unrelated ideas grouped in a sentence--but I'm not an english major :)

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus: See my edit, I changed `\w+` to the set `[\w']+` so that it also captures apostrophes.

Comment: could numbers be added as well? so that everything would be done in one pass? or is it better to keep things separate?

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus: the `re` character `\w` includes the digits 0 through 9, and the underscore, so numbers are already included. Note that this does NOT include decimals of the form `1234.5`. These will come up as separate elements.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use functools much, so I wrote this as a list comprehension.
The one line searches for lone-hyphens and tokens with digits all in one pass.

```
[x for x in your_string.split() if x != '-' and not re.search(r'[0-9]', x)]
```

Using it in an example that has both digits, a stand-alone hyphen, and a hyphen the middle of a word.

```
>>> def foo(your_string):
...     return [x for x in your_string.split() if x != '-' and not re.search(r'[0-9]', x)]
...
>>> your_string = 'Turistguide fikk 40.000 kroner i - bot for smugling MC-ulykke'
>>> foo(your_string)
['Turistguide', 'fikk', 'kroner', 'i', 'bot', 'for', 'smugling', 'MC-ulykke']
```

If you need to handle stand-alone runs of multiple hyphens, the first condition of the `if` is easily modified.

Comment: +1 `re.search(r'[0-9]', x)` Is i think going to be very help full!

Answer (score 0):

Try `reg = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9']+-*[a-zA-Z0-9']*", xs)`

BTW, you don't need the `list()` around `filter()` call in `no_numbers()`.